# Image.save state error 2, invalid parameter. But doesn't seem to have any,

Tags: gdi+

So I'm trying to load BMP file and save it to PNG, simple enough.

I have BMP file ready, which opens fine, and named 'input.bmp'.
Using GDI+, I loaded image using

```
Gdiplus::Image* image = Gdiplus::Image::FromFile(L"input.bmp");
```

and get encoder ID

```
int result = GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &encoderClsid);
```

and save it to png format.

```
stat = image->Save(L"output.png", &encoderClsid);
```

and 'stat' keep gives 2, which is supposed to be invalid parameters.
And does not create any png file.

File names are fixed to input.bmp and output.png since I don't process multiple images at same time.
Whenever I have image ready to convert, I simply call BMP2PNG function.

Anyone have any ideas?
to me, it seems pretty damn similar to MSDN documentation and other people's implementation...

here are full code

```
int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
    UINT  num = 0;          // number of image encoders
    UINT  size = 0;         // size of the image encoder array in bytes

    ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if (size == 0)
        return -1;  // Failure

    pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if (pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
        return -1;  // Failure

    GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);

    for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0)
        {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;  // Success
        }
    }

    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return -1;  // Failure
}

int BMP2PNG()
{
    // Initialize GDI+.
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    CLSID   encoderClsid;
    Status  stat;
    Gdiplus::Image* image = Gdiplus::Image::FromFile(L"input.bmp");
    int result = GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &encoderClsid);

    if (result == -1)
        printf("GetEncoderClsid Error\n");

    stat = image->Save(L"output.png", &encoderClsid);

    if (stat == Ok)
        printf("output.png was saved successfully\n");
    else
        printf("Failure: stat = %d\n", stat);

    delete image;
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 2 for `GetLastStatus` usually indicates that the file name is invalid. This error could have occurred generated earlier, because the input file doesn't exists or it is invalid bitmap file.

Make sure to use full path names. Check for error when opening the file.

```
Gdiplus::Status stat;
Gdiplus::Image* image = Gdiplus::Image::FromFile(L"c:\\fullpath\\input.bmp");
if(!image)
{
    stat = image->GetLastStatus();
    printf("FromFile error %d\n", stat);
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks! When I snippet out the code above and make it separate program, it works just fine. So that's what I did for now. I'll try this method out later if needed.